# HDMI underscan fix

Tags: screen, hdmi

I am using this [Android 4.2 NAND image with my Marsboard A20](http://www.haoyuelectronics.com/service/A10-A20/A20-images/android/MarsBoard_A20_Android_4.2.2_HDMI_720P_V2.0.img.7z).
The HDMI output is working fine but there is some underscan (black borders around the screen).
The image has busybox and rooting pre-installed.

I've found [here i need to edit uEnv.txt in order to fix it](http://www.solid-run.com/community/topic334.html).
Btw, trying to mount the boot partition like this fails:

```
su
mkdir /boot
mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /boot
```

Comment: What resolution does your Marsboard A20 hasve and what your screen? They seem to use different ones, thus the screen adds black borders where the screen region doesn't fit.

Comment: The Android image is set for 720p, while my LCD has a native resolution of 1080p. I've also tried the build set for 1080p and the screen was cropped instead (i could not see a part of it)

Comment: Then your "720p" has probably a different aspect ratio (16:10 instead of your LCD having 16:9) therefore you get those black borders.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit misleading because what you really need to know is how to modify a file inside the boot partition.

Your mount issue is probably there because the boot partition is running from a rootfs image contained in the kernel image and not directly from the mmc-device. You will have to unpack, modify and repack it, but probably it will get easier if you